# Openmp in fortran "Segmentation fault"

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, valgrind

My system is on Debian 12 with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz.

I am trying to parallelize some fortran code with openmp which uses the FFTW library and consists of several modules compiled using the Makefile shown below

```
....
....
LIBS =-lfftw3   

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -O2 
FC = gfortran 
FFLAGS = -O
F90 = gfortran
F90FLAGS = -O3 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -fopenmp  
#F90FLAGS = -O3 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer  
LDFLAGS = -fopenmp  

all: 

main_gradient: $(OBJS) main_gradient.f90
    $(F90) -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $@.f90 
    $(F90) -I$(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -L/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib  $(OBJS) $@.o $(LIBS)  -o $@.exe 


.SUFFIXES: $(SUFFIXES) .f90

%.o: %.f90 
    $(F90)  -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

%.o: $(DIR_GENERAL)/%.f90
    $(F90)  -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

%.o: $(DIR_GEOMETRY)/%.f90
    $(F90)  -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

%.o: $(DIR_POLYMERS)/%.f90
    $(F90)  -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

%.o: $(DIR_INTERACTIONS)/%.f90
    $(F90)  -I$(INCLUDE) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod fort.* dens_* phi* *.exe
....
....
```

For testing purposes I haven't parallelized any of my code yet.

Following information I found online I used allocated arrays for my large arrays (size=64*64*64*100) to solve the segmentation fault when compiling but I still get a segmentation fault when running the executable, even when I have OMP_NUM_THREADS=1. Running it with valgrind gives:

```
==463360== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1ffefff958 --> 0x1ff97ff6f0
==463360==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=92275304 or greater
==463360== Invalid write of size 8
==463360==    at 0x11C7BA: mix_fields.1 (in 
==463360==  Address 0x1ff97ff6f8 is on thread 1's stack
==463360== 
==463360== Can't extend stack to 0x1ff97fe7a8 during signal delivery for thread 1:
==463360==   no stack segment
==463360== 
==463360== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==463360==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FF97FE7A8
==463360==    at 0x11C7BA: mix_fields.1 (in 
==463360==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==463360==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==463360==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==463360==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==463360==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==463360== 
==463360== HEAP SUMMARY:
==463360==     in use at exit: 71,488,141 bytes in 755 blocks
==463360==   total heap usage: 298,496 allocs, 297,741 frees, 1,390,223,513 bytes allocated
==463360== 
==463360== LEAK SUMMARY:
==463360==    definitely lost: 80,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==463360==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==463360==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==463360==    still reachable: 71,408,141 bytes in 754 blocks
==463360==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==463360== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==463360== 
==463360== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==463360== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==463360== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

which from what I understand is a problem with the arrays being allocated to stack and running out of space. What can I do in this situation to get rid of this issue? Does using -fopenmp cause the arrays to be allocated differently than when the -fopenmp flag is not present?

Comment: Note in the above while the answer marked correct gives the reason, the best solution is that given by the second answer. I'm guessing as you present no code, but large, static arrays are really not a good idea - make them allocatable

Comment: Welcome, you must show your code. I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [mcve]. No one can tell you how to fix your code when you do not show it. You say that you "used allocated arrays". How exactly did you do that?

Comment: As I mention above I have looked at this already and made sure most if not all of my arrays are allocated at runtime e.g.:
'''
double precision, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable ::density
...
...
allocate(density(gridx,gridy,gridz,monomer_types),stat=allocStatus)
...
...
'''

Comment: @Vladimir 

The code basically runs in a loop until a convergence of a certain quantity has been reached. Inside the loop, different routines are run that allocate new large arrays and different computations are performed that are then deallocated before the routine is then closed e.g.
```
...
do iter=1,maxinter
...
Calculate Densities(density)
...
*additional subroutines in other modules*
...
end do

subroutine Calculate Density(density)

...
allocate(new array)
...
*perform computation*
...
deallocate(new array)

return 

end subroutine Calculate Density
```

Comment: *most if not all of my arrays are allocated* You must be sure that all of them are. All the big ones that somehow appear in parallel computations. Check what happens when you increase the stack size (if on Linux). We cannot debug a code that we cannot see. The code is *not* optional. A [mcve] must be provided when asking how ti fix an error.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly

```
CFLAGS = -O2 
F90FLAGS = -O3 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -fopenmp
```

You will get better results if you add -g to both of those. And even better still if you use -`fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

I'm not an OpenMP expert, but roughly speaking the OpenMP architecture is to create a thread pool, and then whenever you use stuff like the pragma parallel for, packets of work corresponding to the for loop body will be handed to the thread pool to perform.

As for the stack size, there are two things that you need to consider. By default stack sizes are limited to 8M. You can increase the size limit for the main thread using the shell limit/ulimit command. Thread stack size limits are set when the threads are created, and that can be controlled by the OMP_STACKSIZE environment variable. On top of that Valgrind also imposes its limit for the main thread. As your output says, you can increase that with `--max-stackframe=`.

You can get away with putting a lot on your main thread's stack. Don't put too much on your thread stacks.

You don't say what your 646464*100 array is made up of. If it is floating point doubles then you will need about 520M of memory. I'd round that up to 600M to be safe.